# Magento 2 themes images dont work

Tags: theme, luma-theme

hello guys i have just installed magento 2 on my pc, its the first time i use it. when i log in as an admin i dont see any photos
[image: here's what i see]

also i dont see any images on the folder[image]

does anyone knows what should i do ?
thanks in advance

Comment: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Answer (score 0):

Hi go to terminal and run this command:

This is issue of content-deployment.

**I have assumed you are in Project root directory so run belows command.**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade    
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
sudo chmod -R 777 .
```

Answer (score 0):

if Icons not available and links not working in backend of magento2 follow steps:

```
1. Remove folder pub/static , Note: except .htaccess file
2. Remove folder var/cache
3. Remove folder var/composer_home
4. Remove folder  var/generation
5. Remove folder  var/page_cache
6. Remove folder var/view_preprocessed
7. run in shell php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Open up app/etc/di.xml

find the path in di.xml:
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

and replace it with:
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy

Thanks